# Creating reviews in gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

I've pushed some code to gerrit, creating a branch I believe. I've since updated my code, committed and pushed again (without error), but there is no sign in gerrit of any reviews being created.

Any idea where I should be looking or what step I'm likely to be missing? Thanks in advance.

Edit: Could it be that I'm pushing to master where it should be HEAD:refs/for/something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of the push will tell you what happened, including give you links.

And yes, you should push to `refs/for/master` and not `master` (which will expand to `refs/heads/master` -- bypassing review).